# Zend Framework routing camelcase controllers error

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I'm working on this application with ZendFramework 1.12, using default routing ( controller/action/params ) and everything goes fine in development ( Vagrant + CentOS box ).

But in production server (which is CentOS too) some routes, which uses CamelCase controllers, are not working. Ex.:

`UserProfileController::indexAction()` should map to `/userProfile/index` but when I try it redirects to /home

I know that using "-" to separate the names like in "`/user-profile/index`" it works. But, there's a lot of links in the entire application that need to be fixed.

Anyone knows a better way to make it work?

Comment: When you say it "redirects to home", do you mean it's rendering the home action? Or do you have something in your app that's making it do a redirect? What OS are you using in production? What's the filename of the user profile controller?

Comment: @TimFountain it redirects to "HomeController::indexAction" which is literaly `/home`. we run CentOS too, in production (I'm going to edit the post to add that). .. I have this controller wich filename is `UserProfileController.php` and I'm my links are pointed to `/userProfile`